# VSTO: Problem during creation of a fake email in sent items

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

1. I want to create a fake email in the sent items folder. To achieve this goal:

   a) I am taking a copy of a mail in unsent state

   b) Assigning a GUID as UserProperty

   c) Changing MessageClass = IPM.Post and saving

   d) Info: UserProperty is still existent here

   e) Sending PostItem
2. Within ItemAdd event handler for sent items folder:

   a) I am checking if Item is PostItem

   b) Trying to identify the current object with the set UserProperty (this is already failing, no UserProperties available -> PROBLEM 1)

   c) Want to convert the current PostItem to MailItem by changing MessageClass = IPM.Note and saving

Even I replace 2b with identifying by using the subject instead of UserProperty (as subject is present) after sending I still see the object as PostItem (IPM.Post) and not MailItem (IPM.Note) in sent items -> PROBLEM 2.

When I do a find in sent items, lookup a specific item, change MessageClass = IPM.Note and save, the PostItem is successfully changed to a MailItem.

Regarding Problem 1:
Why are the UserProperties of a PostItem not available during this event?

Regarding Problem 2:
Why I cannot "convert" a PostItem to a MailItem during this event?

How I can solve this natively?

This is my code:

In ThisAddIn:

```
                // ItemSend Event
                Outlook.Application application = this.Application;
                application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(ItemSend_BeforeSend);


...

// ItemAdd event
                outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                Sent_items = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);

                items = Sent_items.Items;
                items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);

...

// ItemAdd event action
                void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
                {
...
                            Outlook.PostItem postItem = Item as Outlook.PostItem;

                            Outlook.UserProperties postUserProperties = null;
                            Outlook.UserProperty postUserProperty = null;

                            // for debug only
                            MessageBox.Show(null ?? postItem.Subject, "TestApp: Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK);


                            try
                            {
                                // start of test part

                                postUserProperties = postItem.UserProperties;
                                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                                for (int i = 1; i <= postUserProperties.Count; i++) // count is 0 here so no UserProperties !!!
                                {
                                    postUserProperty = postUserProperties[i];
                                    if (postUserProperty != null)
                                    {
                                        builder.AppendFormat("Name: {0} \tValue: {1} \n\r",
                                            postUserProperty.Name, postUserProperty.Value);
                                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(postUserProperty);
                                        postUserProperty = null;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (builder.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString(),
                                        "The UserProperties collection");
                                }
                                // end of test part
...
}

// ItemSend_BeforeSend event action
                void ItemSend_BeforeSend(object item, ref bool cancel)
                {
...

 Outlook.Application objOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)objOutlook.Session.OpenSharedItem(MjFileMsg);

                // add we item guid to object in order to identify afterwards
                var mailUserProperty = email.UserProperties.Add("WeItemGuid", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, false, 1);

                createdWeItemGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLower();
                mailUserProperty.Value = createdWeItemGuid;

                email.MessageClass = "IPM.Post";
                email.Save();

                // debug only: check if value is present after changing messageclass (yes, it is present!)
                Outlook.UserProperty testProp = email.UserProperties["WeItemGuid"];
                var testVal = testProp.Value;

                email.Send();
...
}
```

[UPDATE 1]:

This is the updated code in ItemSend event action:

```
                Outlook.Application objOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)objOutlook.Session.OpenSharedItem(MjFileMsg);

                // remove recipients otherwise PostItem will be sent really to recipients (but obviously causing the PostItem not to be sent !!!)
                email.To = null;
                email.CC = null;
                email.BCC = null;

// This has the same effect like setting To/Cc/Bcc to null:
/*
                foreach (Outlook.Recipient Recip in email.Recipients)
                {
                    Recip.Delete();
                }
*/

                email.MessageClass = "IPM.Post";
                email.Save();
                email.Send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you save the message after resetting the message class? Keep in mind that you will also need to wipe out the `PR_ICON_INDEX` property.

You cannot convert `PostItem` to `MailItem` on the fly because Outlook still references the original `PostItem` object. It will see your changes only after both your code and Outlook dereference the object and later reopen it.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am its author), it is as easy as the following (off the top of my head):

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
session.MAPIOBJECT = outlookNameSpace.MAPIOBJECT;
RDOFolder folder = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
RDOMail msg = folder.Items.Add("IPM.Note");
msg.Sent = true;
msg.ReceivedTime = DateRime.Now;
RDOMail originalMsg = (RDOMail)session.GetRDOObjectFromOUtlookObject(Item);
originalMsg.CopyTo(msg);
msg.Sender = session.CurrentUser;
msg.SentOnBehalfOf = session.CurrentUser;
msg.Save();
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, this was helpful. Now I ran into another issue. When I send a postItem with the real recipients, the recipients are really getting this PostItem and I dont want that (it should be just a modified copy of a real email in Sent items). So I thought I remove all recipients during ItemSend event and add again during ItemAdd in Sent Items but now the PostItem is not landing in Sent Items anymore. Cant I send a PostItem without recipients so that it will be written to Sent Items?

Comment: See [UPDATE 1] for previous comment.

Comment: No, if you are trying to send anything, it has to have recipients.

Comment: Are you actually ending anything? Or just creating a fake item in the Sent Items folder?

Comment: a) I am drafting an email, saving a copy, sending one (with encrypted attachment) and want to place an unencrypted version in sent items. The unencrypted one should surely not be sent. 

b) The unencrypted one (can have the same subject) should be displayed within the conversation view in Inbox when someone replies to the encrypted one.

Comment: Maybe I can send the encrypted one first, create a copy of it afterwards, replace body and attachments and save as an unencrypted copy in sent items? If yes, in ItemAdd event or even later once written to sent items?

Comment: Why not simply reset the PR_SECURITY_FLAGS property after the message is sent? That will cause Outlook to remove the decryption from the massage? Or do you mean you are only encrypting an attachment?

Comment: good point, but only the attacment is encrypted with a custom encryption. But now I found a way: a) In ItemSend event I am creating copy of the unencrypted/unsent mail just regarding the body and attachments b) Sending the encrypted one c) In ItemAdd event for sent items I am copying the encrypted one (sent status) and for the copy assigning the unencrypted body and attachments by using the object from a). Flagging the question as solved by Dmitry.

Comment: It would be better to make a copy of the original message (MailItem.Copy / MaiLItem.Move), then remove the encrypted attachment and add the unencrypted one. This way you won't have to deal with the message body  / recipients /etc.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I needed to touch the body and was able to keep the recipients. Working fine now. But now struggling with conversation view. Raised a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996620/what-are-the-item-criterias-for-the-outlook-inbox-conversation-view-of-a-convers

Comment: I answered that question, but it is still better to create a copy with all the hidden properties intact rather than copy one property at a time.